# Abort SQL before DDL operation being executed

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

My question if it's possible to avoid the execution of a DDL operation in an SQL script if the previous operation returns an Error.

SQL script

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;
MERGE finalTABLE using tempTABLE;
DROP tempTABLE;

COMMIT;

EXIT;
```

The first line (*WHENEVER SQLERROR...*) prevents from execute the commit and operations if something went wrong in script execution.
But in this case the DDL operation DROP is being executed.
And in this particular case we DROP the table and content even if the merge/transfer returns an error.

Is there any way to abort DROP execution if MERGE goes wrong.

A simple ERROR: Parent data not found make our day.

The whenever line is defined before the spool command to log returns from sqlplus tool.

logfile for execution:

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connected.
[RS2|rs2]SQL>[RS2|rs2]SQL>


3647465 rows merged.


Table dropped.


Commit complete.

18229970 rows merged.

Table dropped.


Commit complete.


MERGE INTO RS2 val using (SELECT * FROM RS2_TMP) tmp ON (tmp.id = val.id)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (RS2.RS2VAL3) violated - parent key not found

Table dropped.


Commit complete.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.  The  "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT" command halts the executions once an SQL-error occurs. Perhaps there is something  different in the script you're actually using?

Comment: If the merge throws an error then the script will exit immediately, it won't get to the drop. If you think that isn't happening, what is the *full* error message you are seeing from the merge, including the ORA- or SP- number? Or is the real error maybe happening in a trigger and that is converting it to a message with `dbms_output`, and not re-raising it? (Or is the 'error' that it just merges zero rows?)

Comment: Note that the `commit` isn't really needed. The `DROP ...` will already commit the transaction

Comment: Which tool are you using to run that script? `sqlplus`?

Comment: Yes, SQLplus tool is used to execute the script.

Comment: logfile of execution added.

Comment: From the output your script is longer than you showed - are you sure it doesn't have `whenever sqlerror continue` resetting the behaviour between the merge/drop sections?

Comment: The script do the same operation 3 times with 3 different tables. But yes, i will check if the whenever closure is as in mine script in my local machine. It's weird because script is from 2018.

Comment: I think you are taking the wrong approach.  The very fact that you are dropping a "temporary" table indicates that you are not utilizing features that oracle has implemented (and Microsoft has not!).  Whenever you find yourself creating a dropping "temporary" tables, you should step back and consider the use of a [Global Temporary Table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables).

Comment: Just in passing, `EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` is a potential bug, if the OS doesn't support 5-digit return codes.